# Need to override file included in parent theme

Tags: include, parent-theme

I am using a parent theme with built in reservations which is a modification of a reservations plugin by a different developer. It didn't do exactly what we needed we needed so we purchased the standalone premium plugin. It is all working fine except that the parent theme has the following statement in one of the theme files `shortcodes.php`:

```
if (class_exists('rtbInit')) {    
include_once 'bookingtable/bookingtable.php';
}
```

That file breaks the date and time functions of the premium plugin, so, I created a `shortcodes.php` file in the child theme and commented the include line out, but that didn't work. It only works if I comment that line out in the parent theme.

Is there a way to add a function or something to the child theme so that it does **NOT** include that file?

Thank you!

Here is the code for `bookingtable.php`

```
function cs_booking_dequeue_script()
{
if (! is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_style('pickadate-default');
    wp_register_style('pickadate-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/css/classic.css');
    wp_deregister_style('pickadate-date');
    wp_register_style('pickadate-date', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/css/classic.date.css');
    wp_deregister_style('pickadate-time');
    wp_register_style('pickadate-time', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/css/classic.time.css');

    wp_deregister_style('rtb-booking-form');
    wp_dequeue_style('rtb-booking-form');

    wp_deregister_script('rtb-booking-form');
    wp_register_script('rtb-booking-form',get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/js/booking-form.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}

function cs_booking_request_input($input = ''){
  global $rtb_controller;
  $request = $rtb_controller->request;
  //var_dump($request);
  return !empty($request) ? !empty($request->$input) ? $request->$input : null : null;
}

add_shortcode('cs-booking-form', 'cs_booking_form');

function cs_booking_form($params, $content = null)
{
  global $rtb_controller;

//wp_enqueue_style('intlTelInput', get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/css/intlTelInput.css');
//wp_enqueue_script('intlTelInput',get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/js/intlTelInput.min.js', array('jquery'));
//wp_enqueue_script('bookingtable',get_template_directory_uri() . '/framework/shortcodes/bookingtable/js/bookingtable.js', array('intlTelInput'));

// Only allow the form to be displayed once on a page
if ( $rtb_controller->form_rendered === true ) {
    return;
} else {
    $rtb_controller->form_rendered = true;
}

// Enqueue assets for the form
rtb_enqueue_assets();

// Allow themes and plugins to override the booking form's HTML output.
$output = apply_filters( 'rtb_booking_form_html_pre', '' );
if ( !empty( $output ) ) {
    return $output;
}

// Process a booking request
if ( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'booking_request' ) {

    if ( get_class( $rtb_controller->request ) === 'stdClass' ) {
        require_once( RTB_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/Booking.class.php' );
        $rtb_controller->request = new rtbBooking();
    }

    $rtb_controller->request->insert_booking();
}

// Define the form's action parameter
$booking_page = $rtb_controller->settings->get_setting( 'booking-page' );
if ( !empty( $booking_page ) ) {
    $booking_page = get_permalink( $booking_page );
}

$settings = get_option('rtb-settings');

ob_start();

?>
<div class="cs-booking-form">
<?php if ( $rtb_controller->request->request_inserted === true ) : ?>
<div class="rtb-message">
    <p><?php echo $rtb_controller->settings->get_setting( 'success-message' ); ?></p>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
<form id="cs-booking-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $booking_page ? esc_attr( $booking_page ) : get_the_permalink() ; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="booking_request">
    <?php do_action( 'rtb_booking_form_before_fields' ); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="cs-bookTable-date col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label for="rtb-date"><?php esc_html_e( 'When would you like to book?', 'wp_nuvo' ); ?></label>
            <span class="Selectoptions"><input type="text" name="rtb-date" id="rtb-date" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('request_date'); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Select Date', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>"></span>
            <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'date' ); ?>
            <div id="cs-booking-date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cs-bookTable-party col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <label for="rtb-party"><?php esc_html_e( 'Party Size :', 'wp_nuvo' ); ?></label>
            <span class="Selectoptions"><select name="rtb-party" id="rtb-party">
                <?php
                if(empty($settings['party-size'])){ $settings['party-size'] = 20; }
                for($i = 1 ; $i <= $settings['party-size'] ; $i++):
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if(cs_booking_request_input('party') == $i) { echo 'selected'; }?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="cs-bookTable-time col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="rtb-time"><?php esc_html_e( 'Preferred dining time:', 'wp_nuvo' ); ?></label>
            <span class="Selectoptions"><input type="text" name="rtb-time" id="rtb-time" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('request_time'); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Select Time', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>"></span>
            <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'time' ); ?>
            <div id="cs-booking-time"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="name col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
             <input type="text" name="rtb-name" id="rtb-name" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Name', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('name'); ?>">
             <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'name' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="email col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" name="rtb-email" id="rtb-email" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Email', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('email'); ?>">
            <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'email' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="phone col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" name="rtb-phone" id="rtb-phone" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Phone', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('phone'); ?>">
            <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'phone' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="message col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <?php echo rtb_print_form_error( 'message' ); ?>
            <input type="text" name="rtb-message" id="rtb-message" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Message', 'wp_nuvo'); ?>" value="<?php echo cs_booking_request_input('message'); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <?php
        $fields = $rtb_controller->settings->get_booking_form_fields( $rtb_controller->request, array() );
        $_remove = array('date','time','party','name','email','phone','add-message','message');
        foreach( $fields as $fieldset => $contents ) {
            foreach( $contents['fields'] as $slug => $field ) {

                if(in_array($slug, $_remove)) continue;

                $args = empty( $field['callback_args'] ) ? null : $field['callback_args'];

                call_user_func( $field['callback'], $slug, $field['title'], $field['request_input'], $args );
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'rtb_booking_form_after_fields' ); ?>

    <div class="cs-bookTable-submit">
        <button class="btn btn-default rtb-submit" type="submit"><?php esc_html_e( 'BOOK MY TABLE', 'wp_nuvo' ); ?></button>
        <span class="des-text"><?php echo esc_html_e('Please submit your reservation details and we will contact you to confirm your booking ','wp_nuvo');?></span>
    </div>

</form>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?php

$output = ob_get_clean();

$output = apply_filters( 'rtb_booking_form_html_post', $output );

return $output;
}
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question and include the code for `bookingtable/bookingtable.php`? It might be possible to unook things from there. Also, the code posted from shortcodes.php fired from a hook?

Comment: Hi Dave, Shortcodes.php is just a list of include files, the relevant code in that file is what I listed above. Nothing surrounds it.    bookingtable.php, however DOES consist of three functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you would have to edit the parent theme as there is no way to overwrite the `include_once 'bookingtable/bookingtable.php';`.

So to keep edits to the parent theme minimal, the whole code can be rewritten using wordpress `get_template_part()` as

```
if ( class_exists('rtbInit') ) {    
    get_template_part('bookingtable/bookingtable');
}
```

This way you can then copy the file to your child theme and make edits there.

Comment: Thank you, Tunji, but I have no need for the bookingtable.php file, so if I need to edit the parent theme, the easiest thing is just to comment out the include line.  I just need to remember to do this again each time I update the parent theme - which is what I was trying to avoid.